# Which is the best way to keep SSL Certificate file in mobile application?

Tags: android, web-services, ssl, https

In android app we keep SSL certificate in resource raw folder.But my question is, Is this is a secured way to keep SSL certificate in mobile app.Is it possible to keep SSL certificate in server or get from the server?

- How to keep SSL certificate in mobile banking application for secure connection.
- How i can update SSL certificate without updating mobile app from play store.